# filter combobox value based on another combobox but at runtime combobox 2 is empty

Tags: c#, combobox, filter

HI I have 2 comboboxes (Ex cb1,cb2) one has machine group and another has machines in it.
when I select cb1 it should display total without filtering cb2 but when i choose cb2 it should filter the records.everything works fine but default text is not been displayed in combobox2 (like total or all machines) 
My question is when I select combobox1 the total is displayed but combobox2 is empty it should display text with total/all machines in it I tried several ways I cant do that.

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        try
        {
            this.dtStartDate.Value = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3);
            this.dtEndDate.Value = DateTime.Now;
            PopulateGroupList();
            cboMachines.Items.Insert(0, "-ALL MACHINES-");
            cboMachines.SelectedIndex = 0;
            //cboMachines.SelectedText = "Please Select One";
            cboMachineGroup.SelectedText = "Please Select One";
           //this.cboMachineGroup.SelectedIndex = 0;
            PopulateMachineList();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        btnShowForDateRange.Enabled = true;
    }


    private void PopulateMachineList()
    {
        cboMachines.Items.Clear();

        string stringSql = "SELECT DISTINCT lfh.OriginalMachineName   " +
        "FROM MachineGroups mg    " +
        "INNER JOIN MachineGroupList mgl   " +
        "ON (mg.GroupID = mgl.GroupID)    " +
        "INNER JOIN LogFileHeader lfh ON (mgl.MachineID = lfh.FKMachineID)   " +
         "WHERE mg.Name=@groupname " +
        "ORDER BY lfh.OriginalMachineName" ;



        DataTable myDatatable = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection();
        myConn.ConnectionString = connString;


        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand();
        myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        myCommand.CommandText = stringSql;
        myCommand.Connection = myConn;
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@groupname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.cboMachineGroup.Text;
        myConn.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                this.cboMachines.Items.Add(reader[0].ToString());
            }
        }

    }

    private void PopulateGroupList()
    {
        string stringSql = "SELECT DISTINCT mg.Name FROM MachineGroups mg ORDER BY Name";
        DataTable myDatatable = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection();
        myConn.ConnectionString = connString;

        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand();
        myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        myCommand.CommandText = stringSql;
        myCommand.Connection = myConn;
        myConn.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows) 
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                this.cboMachineGroup.Items.Add(reader.GetString(0));
            }
        }

    }

    public DataTable GetDataByMachineGroupAndDateRange(string startDate, string endDate, string machineGroupname, string machineID)
    {

        startDate = startDate + " 00:00:00";
        endDate = endDate + " 23:59:59";

        string stringSql = "";
        if (machineID.Length >0) 
        {



            stringSql = "SELECT mg.GroupID, mg.Name,  " +
        "CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),rta.IDdatetime,121) AS date_only, " +
        "CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), rta.IDdatetime, 108) AS time_only, " +
        "rta.TicketPrice, rta.CardAmount, rta.FKTariffID, rta.RegistrationNum, rta.ExpiryDateTime, " +
        "lfh.OriginalMachineName " +
        "FROM MachineGroups mg  " +
        "INNER JOIN MachineGroupList mgl " +
        "ON (mg.GroupID = mgl.GroupID)  " +
        "INNER JOIN LogFileHeader lfh ON (mgl.MachineID = lfh.FKMachineID)  " +
        "INNER JOIN RegistrationTransactionData rta ON (lfh.PKId = rta.FKLogFileHeader) " +
        "WHERE mg.Name=@groupname  AND lfh.OriginalMachineName=@machineid " +
        "AND rta.IDdatetime BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate " +
        "ORDER BY rta.IDdatetime" ;
        }



        else
        {
            stringSql = "SELECT mg.GroupID, mg.Name,  " +
       "CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),rta.IDdatetime,121) AS date_only, " +
       "CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), rta.IDdatetime, 108) AS time_only, " +
       "rta.TicketPrice, rta.CardAmount, rta.FKTariffID, rta.RegistrationNum, rta.ExpiryDateTime, " +
       "lfh.OriginalMachineName " +
       "FROM MachineGroups mg  " +
       "INNER JOIN MachineGroupList mgl " +
       "ON (mg.GroupID = mgl.GroupID)  " +
       "INNER JOIN LogFileHeader lfh ON (mgl.MachineID = lfh.FKMachineID)  " +
       "INNER JOIN RegistrationTransactionData rta ON (lfh.PKId = rta.FKLogFileHeader) " +
       "WHERE mg.Name=@groupname " +
       "AND rta.IDdatetime BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate " +
       "ORDER BY rta.IDdatetime";
        }


        DataTable myDatatable = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection();
        myConn.ConnectionString = connString;

        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand();
        myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        myCommand.CommandText = stringSql;
        myCommand.Connection = myConn;

        SqlDataAdapter myAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand;

        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@groupname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = machineGroupname;
        if (machineID.Length > 0)
        {
            myCommand.Parameters.Add("@machineid", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = machineID;

        }
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@startdate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = startDate;
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@enddate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = endDate;


        myAdapter.Fill(myDatatable);

        return myDatatable;
    }

    private void btnShowForDateRange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        tblDateRange = new DataTable();
        this.btnShowForDateRange.Enabled = false;
        this.btnFindVRM.Enabled = false;
        this.progressBar1.Visible = true;
        btnExport.Enabled = false;
        this.cboMachines.SelectedText = "ALL Machines";
        string[] parameters = { dtStartDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), dtEndDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), this.cboMachineGroup.Text, this.cboMachines.Text  };
        this.backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(parameters);

    }

    private void btnQuit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] parameters = (string[])e.Argument;
        tblDateRange = GetDataByMachineGroupAndDateRange(parameters[0], parameters[1], parameters[2], parameters[3]);  
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = tblDateRange;
        this.btnShowForDateRange.Enabled = true;
        this.btnFindVRM.Enabled = true;
        this.progressBar1.Visible = false;
        this.lblCount.Visible = true;
        this.lblCount.Text = "Count: " + tblDateRange.Rows.Count.ToString();
        tblVRM = new DataTable();
        btnExport.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void cboMachineGroup_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //this.cboMachines.Text = "";

        PopulateMachineList();
    }

    private void cboMachines_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnFindVRM_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tblVRM = new DataTable();
        this.btnShowForDateRange.Enabled = false;
        this.btnFindVRM.Enabled = false;
        this.progressBar1.Visible = true;
        btnExport.Enabled = false;

        string[] parameters = { txtVRM.Text };
        this.backgroundWorker2.RunWorkerAsync(parameters);
    }


    public DataTable GetDataByVRM(string vrm_in)
    {

        string stringSql = "SELECT mg.GroupID, mg.Name,  " +
       "CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),rta.IDdatetime,121) AS date_only, " +
       "CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), rta.IDdatetime, 108) AS time_only, " +
       "rta.TicketPrice, rta.CardAmount, rta.FKTariffID, rta.RegistrationNum, rta.ExpiryDateTime, " +
       "lfh.OriginalMachineName " +
       "FROM MachineGroups mg  " +
       "INNER JOIN MachineGroupList mgl " +
       "ON (mg.GroupID = mgl.GroupID)  " +
       "INNER JOIN LogFileHeader lfh ON (mgl.MachineID = lfh.FKMachineID)  " +
       "INNER JOIN RegistrationTransactionData rta ON (lfh.PKId = rta.FKLogFileHeader) " +
       "WHERE rta.RegistrationNum=@vrm AND mg.Name NOT IN ('Mains','ALL','ANPR') " +
       "ORDER BY rta.IDdatetime";

        DataTable myDatatable = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection();
        myConn.ConnectionString = connString;

        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand();
        myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        myCommand.CommandText = stringSql;
        myCommand.Connection = myConn;

        SqlDataAdapter myAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand;

        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@vrm", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = vrm_in;

        myAdapter.Fill(myDatatable);

        return myDatatable;
    }

    private void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] parameters = (string[])e.Argument;
        tblVRM = GetDataByVRM(parameters[0]); 
    }

    private void backgroundWorker2_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = tblVRM;
        this.btnShowForDateRange.Enabled = true;
        this.btnFindVRM.Enabled = true;
        this.progressBar1.Visible = false;
        this.lblCount.Visible = true;
        this.lblCount.Text = "Count: " + tblVRM.Rows.Count.ToString();
        tblDateRange = new DataTable();
        btnExport.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you clear the ComboBox Items collection in "PopulateMachines" you have to add the item again

```
private void cboMachineGroup_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //this.cboMachines.Text = "";

    PopulateMachineList();
    cboMachines.Items.Insert(0, "-ALL MACHINES-");
    cboMachines.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Second Try:

```
private void btnShowForDateRange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    tblDateRange = new DataTable();
    this.btnShowForDateRange.Enabled = false;
    this.btnFindVRM.Enabled = false;
    this.progressBar1.Visible = true;
    btnExport.Enabled = false;
    cboMachines.Items.Insert(0, "-ALL MACHINES-");
    cboMachines.SelectedIndex = 0;
    string[] parameters = { dtStartDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), dtEndDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), this.cboMachineGroup.Text, this.cboMachines.Text  };
    this.backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(parameters);

}
```

Comment: Hi Romano, I tried it but my datagridview  is empty when I select from cboxMachinegroup but cbomachine has allmachine in it . thanks

Comment: Hi Kiran, I'm not really sure if I get your problem. In the question you did not write anything from the DataGridView. Could you edit your question and replace cb1,cb2 and combobox1,combobox2 with the names of the objects in code. Would really help to understand it better

Comment: I just want to display text as (all machines/total) on combobox2 when i select from combobox1. everything work fine with code.

Comment: I think then my code should do this. Assuming that combobox1 is cboMachineGroup.

Comment: Hi Romano, I have 2 comboboxes, one datagrid view, to display data filtered from comboboxes when I select combobox1 and click on button itdisplays the total data on datagridview (combobox 2 empty) when i filter combobox1 and combobox2 it displays filtered data. now my question is when I select combobox1 and click button the comb obox 2 should have a text as total instead of being blank or empty

Comment: Hi  Romano, Do you want any pic that gives us a better idea of what i am trying to acheive

Comment: combobox1- cbomachinegroup and combobox2 - cbomachines

Comment: A picture could be helpfull.

Comment: I think I got what you mean. Plaese try the code under "second Try". :-)

Comment: I tried it again but still no luck.. my cbomachines is filtered it has values in it but my first index in mycbomachines is empty and in the second it says M24,M25 (those are machines).

Comment: On which button do you click?

Comment: cbomachineGroup _selectedIndexedChanged is my code .. btnShowforDateRange is my button